# How to make antd sidebar menu items active depending on the current url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

I am using antd Menu and Menu Item components. My application is such that if you click on a particular menu item the url changes and that menu item is selected. However if you are on dashboard, you can also click on a button that changes the url to the same one as clicked on that particular menu item but in that case the menu item does not get selected. How to solve this issue:

```
              <Menu
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                mode="vertical"
              >
                <Link to="/dashboard">
                   <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
                     Dashboard
                   </Menu.Item>
                 </Link>
                <Link to="/add-recipe">
                   <Menu.Item key="app" disabled icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
                     Add Recipes
                   </Menu.Item>
                 </Link>
              </Menu>
```

Now in the dashboard component there is also a button that allows user to directly add recipe from there and changes url upon click but the Add Recipe menu item does not selected becuase it is not manually clicked. How to make it active depending on url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and I had to use the props `selectedKeys` in `Menu` and use  hooks and state to set the current item selected.
To make this works, keys must have the same value as the link.

**Example :**

```
function Navigation() {
    let location = useLocation();
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(
        location.pathname === "/" || location.pathname === ""
            ? "/dashboard"
            : location.pathname,
    );
    //or simply use const [current, setCurrent] = useState(location.pathname)        

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location) {
            if( current !== location.pathname ) {
                setCurrent(location.pathname);
            }
        }
    }, [location, current]);

    function handleClick(e: any) {
        setCurrent(e.key);
    }

    return (
        <Menu
            onClick={handleClick}
            mode="vertical"
            selectedKeys={[current]}
          >
            <Link to="/dashboard">
               <Menu.Item key="/dashboard" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
                 Dashboard
               </Menu.Item>
             </Link>
            <Link to="/add-recipe">
               <Menu.Item key="/add-recipe" disabled icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
                 Add Recipes
               </Menu.Item>
             </Link>
          </Menu>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      '& .MuiPaper-root': {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      },
    },
    active: {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      '& .MuiTypography-body1': {
        fontWeight: 600,
      },
      // backgroundColor: 'green'
      '& .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
        color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
    },
  }),
);


     const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState('');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setActiveLink(window.location.pathname);
      }, []);
```

Now in your Menu.item you can apply an active class.

```
<Menu.Item
className={{path-from-fetched-from-onClick)} === activeLink ? `${classes.active}` : ''}>
...
</Menu.Item>
```

It might be the case that you've to apply this on your Link, instead of Menu item. But I'm sure it'll will solve the problem.

Comment: This works partially but the problem is that two menu items are selected at one because I am adding the active class to add recipes menu item but the dashboard one is not removed. How to remove that?

Comment: @Emma it will automatically remove the active class from the component which doesn't match with URL, and only applies to the class to new selected. It works fine with me.